# Custom Font rendering issue using wkhtmltoimage

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, fonts, wkhtmltoimage

I am trying to use rails ERB template to render an object in HTML and then convert it to an image using websnap (which uses wkhtmltoimage).  As it happens I am using a custom font (Bello) that I installed on my mac in the HTML page and I notice that the font is not rendered properly (some characters have missing font color).  Has anyone encountered this problem?  Can it be fixed or is it a wkhtmltoimage rendering bug?

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Hi, did you have any success with that problem?